# instance method beginAnimations:context: not found

Tags: iphone, ios4

i am trying to add animation to move my buttons from left to right.

i have added the following code

```
[self.view beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[self.view setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[button setFrame:newFrame];
[self.view commitAnimations];
```

but when i build, i see the warning "instance method beginAnimations:context: not found"

I have added QuartzCore framework and included

```
#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>
```

Can someone please tell what am i missing?

Thank you

Comment: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> try and tell me

Comment: thx Piyush, i did try that, getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing quartz headers is not necessary.

`beginAnimations:context:` is a class method. You are calling it on an instance of UIView. The same applies for `setAnimationDuration` and `commitAnimations`. Replace `self.view` with `UIView` or, better, use block-based animations instead.

Your code, corrected:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f]; 
[button setFrame:newFrame]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Block-based (iOS4.0 and later):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{[button setFrame:newFrame];}];
```

Based on your comments, you are missing my point. These methods are **class** methods. you need to call them directly to `UIView` - the **class**. Not to `self.view`, which is an **instance of UIView**. Look at the line of code above - the message is being sent to `UIView`. Use the exact line of code above. Copy and paste if you like. I'm not using UIView as a placeholder for "insert a view object here!", it's the code you have to use.

Comment: thx jrturton, i used [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{[button setFrame:newFrame];}]; but still showing error "instance method animateWithDuration:animations: not found"

Comment: Are you sure that is your exact code? Because if you'd used UIView, it wouldn't be telling you about instance methods.

Comment: jrturton, thank you so much for helping. i am using the exact code. here is NSLog of self.view                                        <UIView: 0x6887070; frame = (0 0; 320 411); autoresize = W+H; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6887320>>                  i put [self.view animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 50, 50)];}];                                i also tried UIView *view = (UIView *) self.view and called             [view animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 50, 50)];}];

Comment: You're not using the exact code. See my edit. You can't call class methods on an instance of the class.

Comment: thank you so much jrturton, it is working now, really sorry, i did not understand.